# Add multiple comments to different cells depending on cell value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add different comments to different cells based on cells values

```
Sub comment()

Dim ColNum As Long

With Worksheets("MARC")

ColNum = .UsedRange.Columns.Count



Select Case Cells(1, ColNum).Value
    Case Is = "Batch Management"
                .AddComment
                .comment.Text Text:="Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC"
    End Select
    
  End With
End Sub
```

but this code is not returning anything. I want to find the column header with the value "Batch Management" and add a comment " Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC". I need to do this for multiple cells (different values and comments)

Answer (score 0):

This Worked:

```
    Sub comment()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Selection

    Select Case cell.Value
      Case Is = "Batch Management"
                cell.AddComment
                cell.comment.Text Text:="Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC"
       End Select
    
   Next cell

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Users don't have to select the header before executing code, pls try.
- Note: if the data table doesn't start from A1, revising code is needed

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub comment()
    Dim ColNum As Long
    With Worksheets("MARC")
        For ColNum = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            With .Cells(1, ColNum)
                Select Case .Value
                Case Is = "Batch Management"
                    .AddComment
                    .comment.Text Text:="Should see X for ZFIN & ZSFG & ZCNC"
'                Case Is = ""
'                   ' more keywords
                End Select
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

- If you need to match many keywords, consider using two arrays to make the code more organized.
- You can store the keywords / comments in a work sheet and load it into an array by VBA.

```vb
Sub comment2()
    Dim ColNum As Long
    Dim aKeyWord, aCmt, vIndex
    aKeyWord = Array("Batch Management", "Time Management", "Risk Management")
    aCmt = Array("Batch Comment", "Time Comment", "Risk Comment")
    With Worksheets("MARC")
        For ColNum = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            With .Cells(1, ColNum)
                vIndex = Application.Match(.Value, aKeyWord, 0)
                If Not IsError(vIndex) Then
                    .AddComment
                    .comment.Text Text:=aCmt(vIndex)
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```